# Should I trim my cat’s fur underneath the paw as she doesn’t have much grip inside the house but it is around 2 degrees Celsius outside in the garden

Tags: cats

Will it help my cat getting better traction on a slippery floor if i trim the fur on her toes?

Comment: This seems to be incomplete. Please click [edit] to add more information.

Comment: i think you should change your question a bit,maybe to something like will it help my cat getting better traction on a slippery floor if i trim the fur on her toes.the start of your question looks a bit opinion based as it is now.

Comment: the age of your cat is important to know when answering this question,a senior cat will have the same problems on a slippry floor as senior people have.

Comment: How long have you had the cat? I have three, one with long fur between her toes; all three slide on the floor at times, and it didn't take terribly long for the one with longer fur to adapt to the floors. She has zero issues getting around a living space with virtually no carpet/rugs at all.

Comment: I’ve had her for almost a year so she’s quite a young cat, she’s fine on a daily basis it’s just she sometimes crashes if she’s running.

Comment: Is this your first cat? Short-haired cats will also often "crash" while running on uncarpeted floors.

Comment: Ah right thank you very much.

Comment: @AllisonC Ours (short-haired, 8yo) recently discovered how to slide on purpose(!) on tile floors and does so with obvious glee when catching treats or toys. Yilin, did you in purpose remove the half-sentence about your cat also being outside and what effects this could have?

Comment: I have never heard of cats using toe beans as the primary source of traction. They use their nails. Is your cat declawed? This might change the equation. Assuming your cat is long-haired, because mostly the hair of long-haired outgrows the toe beans, if you trim the paw hair just a little to make it as long as the paw hair of short-haired cats, she won't be too cold with the trimmed hair.

More information about your cat and a video of her having less traction than it is supposed to would help.